# Need help in histogram displaying the stars

Tags: java, histogram, netbeans-8

I need help with displaying the stars for each cat1 to cat4. the problem I'm having is, the stars are being displayed below the cat1 to cat4 when you run the code. I want the stars to be displayed at the side of each cat.

The output of my coding is:

Read in a mark
21

Enter the next student mark
2

Enter the next student mark
30

Enter the next student mark
31

Enter the next student mark
40

Enter the next student mark
41

Enter the next student mark
70

Enter the next student mark
71

Enter the next student mark
109 = when the person enters a number over 100 the while loop ends.

Total number of marks entered 8

0-29: 2

*

*

30-39: 2

*

*

40-69: 2

*

*

70-100: 2

*

*

what I  expected the coding to look like :
0-29: 
*
*

30-39: 
*
*

40-69: 
*
*

70-100: 
*
*

```
    int cat1 = 0;
    int cat2 = 0;
    int cat3 = 0;
    int cat4 = 0;
    int mark;
    int counter = 0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Read in a mark");
    mark = input.nextInt();

    while (mark <= 100 && mark >= 0) {
        counter++;
        if (mark >= 0 && mark <= 29) {
            cat1++;
        }
        if (mark >= 30 && mark <= 39) {
            cat2++;
        }
        if (mark >= 40 && mark <= 69) {
            cat3++;
        }
        if (mark >= 70 && mark <= 100) {
            cat4++;
        }

        System.out.println("Enter the next student mark");
        mark = input.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Total number of marks entered " + counter);

    System.out.print("");
    System.out.println("0-29: " + cat1);
    for (int i = 0; i < cat1; i++) {
        System.out.println("*");
    }
    System.out.print("");
    System.out.println("30-39: " + cat2);
    for (int i = 0; i < cat2; i++) {
        System.out.println("*");
    }
    System.out.print("");
    System.out.println("40-69: " + cat3);
    for (int i = 0; i < cat3; i++) {
        System.out.println("*");
    }
    System.out.print("");
    System.out.println("70-100: " + cat4);
    for (int i = 0; i < cat4; i++) {
        System.out.println("*");
    }
```

Comment: I meant I want the stars to be displayed on the right side of each cat1 to cat4 but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Can you provide your output and the expected output?

Comment: I've done some editing to the question I asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change `System.out.println` to `System.out.print` and add a `System.out.println();` at the end after each loop

```
System.out.print("");
System.out.print("0-29: " + cat1);
for (int i = 0; i < cat1; i++) {
    System.out.print("*");
}
System.out.println();
System.out.print("");
System.out.print("30-39: " + cat2);
for (int i = 0; i < cat2; i++) {
    System.out.print("*");
}
System.out.println();
System.out.print("");
System.out.print("40-69: " + cat3);
for (int i = 0; i < cat3; i++) {
    System.out.print("*");
}
System.out.println();
System.out.print("");
System.out.print("70-100: " + cat4);
for (int i = 0; i < cat4; i++) {
    System.out.print("*");
}
System.out.println();
```

probably you should also add some white spaces where needed

Comment: woow something so simple I didn't even notice

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

```
        String star = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < cat1; i++) {
            star = star +"*";
        }
        System.out.println("0-29: " + star);
```